# how to prevent git commit renaming a directory start with dot

Tags: git, git-commit

I am trying to git commit a directory starting with a dot as required by a partner. Whenever I do that, I am seeing github move the files underneath to its parent directory.

How can I prevent it from renaming?

```
ls directory 
app
  |_ .well-known
      |_ apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt
```

> git commit -m 'added association file'

results in

```
rename assets/{ => .well-known}/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt (100%)

ls directory 
app
  |_ apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention GitHub: GitHub is literally unable to change anything that you have committed locally. This change must be happening locally, on your machine, not on GitHub. Meanwhile, Git itself has no issues with such a directory. Perhaps you have a pre-commit hook that renames files?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fresh git repository? The output makes it look like you're actually moving files. Show the output of `git status` before you do the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Commit command gives me the following hint:

```
Untracked files:
    .well-known/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

You need to run `git add` command:

```
git add .well-known/*
```

Then commit & push will create `.well-known` directory with your file on GitHub.